# How can I create a node and use to this node in query at the same time in Neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have two queries in Neo4j as following,

```
MERGE (temp:Temp)
SET temp = {tid: 'blabla', title_ids: [], pid: 'blabla'}
```

Firstly I'm creating a node with query as above. Then, I am running to code following query,

```
CALL apoc.periodic.commit(
    "
    MATCH(temp:Temp)
    WITH temp
    MATCH (t1:Title)-[r:TO]->(t2:Title)
    WHERE t1.tid = temp.tid
    AND NOT exists((t2)<-[:LIKE|:DISLIKE|:LOVE]-(:User {pid: temp.pid}))
    AND NOT t2.tid IN temp.title_ids
    AND t2.tid <> temp.tid
    WITH COLLECT(r) AS relationships, SUM(r.weight) AS total
    UNWIND relationships AS relation
    WITH COLLECT([relation.weight / total, ENDNODE(relation).tid]) AS rels
    LIMIT 1
    
    MATCH(temp:Temp)
    WITH temp, rels
    CALL apoc.do.when(
        SIZE(rels) > 0 AND SIZE(temp.title_ids) < 10,
        '
        WITH
        REDUCE(
            s={x: rand()}, r IN rels | CASE
            WHEN s.x IS NULL THEN s
            WHEN s.x < r[0] THEN {x: NULL, target: r[1]}
            ELSE {x: s.x - r[0]} END
        ).target AS target
        SET $temp.tid = target, $temp.title_ids = $temp.title_ids + target
        RETURN 1 AS result
        ',
        'RETURN 0 AS result',
        {temp: temp, rels: rels}
    ) YIELD value
    RETURN value.result
    "
) YIELD batchErrors

MATCH (temp:Temp)
WITH temp.title_ids AS titles
MATCH(title:Title)
WHERE title.tid IN titles
RETURN title
```

There is no problem so far. But when I run these queries together, I get an error like that,

> WITH is required between SET and CALL (line 4, column 1 (offset: 76))
> "CALL apoc.periodic.commit("
> ^

My first question is how can I merge these queries and run together?
And the second question is optional. I'm newbie in Neo4j, so I'm sure there are some easier ways to optimize these queries. How can I edit these queries to better?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error states, you need to specify a [WITH](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/with/) clause between a `SET` and a `CALL`.

So, just do this:

```
MERGE (temp:Temp)
SET temp = {tid: 'blabla', title_ids: [], pid: 'blabla'}
WITH temp
CALL apoc.periodic.commit(
...
```

and near the bottom of your query, you can remove the `MATCH (temp:Temp)` clause.

With respect to query tuning, you should read the [documentation](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/query-tuning/). There are also many related questions in Stackoverflow.

Comment: This query is not giving an error right now. But also unfortunately not returning correct result. That always return empty list. Do you have any idea about that?

Comment: Can you try running your 2 original queries again? Do you get results from the second query?

Comment: Yes, if I run these queries separately, it returns a list with 10 elements.

Comment: Interesting. I wonder if `temp` has stale data for some reason after the `CALL`. Try starting off with `MERGE (t:Temp)
SET t = {tid: 'blabla', title_ids: [], pid: 'blabla'}
WITH 1 CALL ...`, and keeping the `MATCH (temp:Temp)` clause at the bottom.

Comment: I tried with `WITH 1 AS x` and that just creating a temp node. `apoc` statement never run.